# Adding sizing handles to drawn object in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a full screen canvas I am drawing to, and I've set it up to allow the user to drag and drop objects that are within the canvas.

I also want to enable them to select an object, and then 'resize handlers' show up (the little circles in the corners) to allow them to click/drag and resize them.

I can code this manually by drawing circles in each corner and detect a click, etc.... but was wondering if anyone has any better way to do this? Maybe there's a library out there that already handles this?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/test/demo/)?

Comment: Kangax - thanks a ton, your library is perfect and is very very impressive. I was thinking of building something similar, but looks like you've already done it. Instead, I filed a bug, and maybe I'll find a way to contribute :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't any simpler way than doing it yourself or getting a library to do it for you.

I wrote a tutorial [here](http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape) on the use of sizing handles. That should get you started if you plan to make your own.

Comment: I was wondering if someone knows a something like that in Flex SDK??

Comment: Link does not work, please update

Comment: Link still broken
Nice website though!